# Problem installing jupyter notebook

Tags: 16.04, bash, python, python3, pip

I'm trying to install jupyter notebook using pip command in ubuntu 16.04. python3 and pip latest version are already installed in my machine. so when i run :

```
$ pip install jupyter
```

I'm seeing this warning-

```
-bash: /usr/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

does it mean that python and pip are not linked? I read from similar questions posted on askubuntu but none seems to address my problem

I've also tried :

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

then it says:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python': File exists
```

where do I need to fix it, can someone help?

Comment: Try `pip3` instead. Also, add the output of `namei -lx /usr/bin/python`, please.

Comment: but when i tried to upgrade pip using `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and install jupyter notebook again , I'm getting  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please also add the output of `apt-cache policy python-minimal $(dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/python | cut -d: -f1)`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
pip2 install virtualenv
virtualenv jupyter
source jupyter/bin/activate
pip2 install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

This solution was tested on:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

It was run on 32bit Chromenotebook
[Firefox and terminal shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPEQC.png)